# How to add an array to an array in javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-maps

I will be getting `coordinates` as

`25.774252, -80.190262`

`18.466465, -66.118292`

`32.321384, -64.75737`

I have to maintain an array like

`Coordinates[] = [(25.774252, -80.190262),(18.466465, -66.118292),(32.321384, -64.75737)]`

How is this possible? Or is there any other method to get latitude and longitude point by point?

I tried like,

```
for(var i = 0 ; i < polygonBounds.length ; i++)
{
     coordinates.push(polygonBounds.getAt(i).lat(), polygonBounds.getAt(i).lng()); 
}
```

but it will be like,

```
0
    31.796473239688435

1
    -106.51227951049805

2
    31.797786324219413

3
    -106.49425506591797

4
    31.78392504670159

5
    -106.47829055786133

6
    31.757509914027327

7
    -106.48704528808594

8
    31.776191009772532

9
    -106.52069091796875

10
    31.790782991145434

11
    -106.5208625793457
```

So now i have this array i need to take each latitude and longitude by looping the same array. How is it possible?

Comment: You want `coordinates.push([polygonBounds.getAt(i).lat(), polygonBounds.getAt(i).lng()]);`?

Comment: if you want to push an array: .push([val1, val2])

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want to push pairs, push an array:

```
for (var i = 0; i < polygonBounds.length; i++) {
     coordinates.push([polygonBounds.getAt(i).lat(), polygonBounds.getAt(i).lng()]); 
}
```

it would be the short for:

```
for (var i = 0; i < polygonBounds.length; i++) {
     var coords = [];
     coords.push(polygonBounds.getAt(i).lat());
     coords.push(polygonBounds.getAt(i).lng());
     coordinates.push(coords); 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

have you tried :

```
for(var i = 0 ; i < polygonBounds.length ; i++)
{
     coordinates.push([polygonBounds.getAt(i).lat(), polygonBounds.getAt(i).lng()]); 
}
```

(notice the '[' and ']')?

Answer (score 0):

`(25.774252, -80.190262)` is not a valid value, so it can't be stored in array.

You must use array or object instead of it.

`[25.774252, -80.190262]` or `{lat: 25.774252, lng: -80.190262}`

Answer (score 0):

try at

```js
for(var i = 0 ; i < polygonBounds.length ; i++)
{
    var obj = {};
    obj.x = polygonBounds.getAt(i).lat();
    obj.y = polygonBounds.getAt(i).lng();
    coordinates.push(obj); 
}
```

and get `var some = coordinates[0].x;`

Answer (score 0):

What you need is an array of objects where every object stores two properties

```
var coordinates = [];
for(var i=0; i<polybounds.length; i+=2) {
    coordinates.push({ lat: polybounds[i], long: polybounds[i+1] });
}
```

Now you can do anything on coordinates with something like,

```
for(var i=0; i<coordinates.length; i+=2) {
    var long = coordinates[i].long;
    var lat = coordinates[i].lat;
    console.log(lat + ',' + long);
}
```